# If power consumed in a resistor is equal to the power supplied by the the source, then why doesn't the flow of charges stop?

Tags: electricity, electric-current

So the energy given to the charge (assume it to be positive) in unit time is completely consumed when it crosses the resistor, why does the charge still flows towards the battery.

Comment: If "the source" has a limited supply of _energy_ (e.g., if the source is a charged capacitor, or a battery, or a generator that only has so-much fuel in its tank) then the flow of charges eventually _will_ stop.

Comment: What makes you think that the energy is "completely consumed?"

Comment: @Matteo This is a possible answer. Don't post it in the comments, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general when the power supplied to a system $P_S(t)$ equals the power loss $P_L(t)$, i.e. $P_S(t)=P_L(t)$ for every $t$, this does not imply that the system is at rest. The only conclusion is that the system is in a stationary state.
In other words, this means that the present situation does not evolve in time, not that everything is at rest.

For instance you can take the vertical motion of a body in a viscous fluid: after some time the potential power provided by gravity equals the power loss due to viscous friction: but the particle does not stop: it simply moves with constant velocity, so it's in a stationary state. 
The situation of a charge is very similar, but gravity is replaced by voltage and friction by electric resistance. (Actually this analogy is precisely the idea behind Drude's model of conductivity).

Moreover, in general from $P_S(t)=P_L(t)$ you can only argue stationarity, not even equilibrium!

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into the details and equations of the time behavior, when a battery/resistor circuit path is first closed, the current climbs to a steady-state value. This is because a path through which electrons can easily flow has been provided. Before that connection, whatever path one could imagine was highly resistive, approaching infinity. The current, practically, is zero but may be attoamperes. The reason the charge flows is because of the chemical reaction in the battery producing a charge segregation at the terminals. From Coulombs law, we know that there are forces trying to reduce that segregation, so when a lower resistance path (compared to the chemical reaction potential which forces the segregation) exists, charge will begin to flow. It takes a few microseconds to go from zero to steady-state, and (here's a key point), that particular steady-state depends on the resistance of the circuit.

If there is nothing to catch and hold the charge (wires and resistors don't catch and hold), once reaching a steady-state current, however much charge flows into a volume per unit time must also flow out. That's called continuity of flow. The power consumption is a time derivative (a slope) of the energy delivered, so at steady-state, the energy *per second* removal rate matches the energy *per second* delivery rate. But the charges are already moving due to that start-up moment.

An analogy would be a hand pushing a block at constant velocity on a friction surface. The power in equals the power out once the block gets moving, but there is still some energy in the system due to the initial push.